# Add role by ID discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

I've tried relentlessly for about 1-2hrs to get this piece of code to work. I need to add the role to a user, simple enough right?

This code, searches for the role but cannot find it, is this because I am sending it from a channel which that role doesn't have access to? I need help please.

Edit 1: removed quotations around the ID

```
@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.User):
    #Add the customer role to the user
    role_id = 810264985258164255

    guild = ctx.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=810264985258164255)
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

```
2021-03-06T21:12:51.811235+00:00 app[worker.1]: Your bot is ready.
2021-03-06T21:14:09.010057+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command addrole:
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012477+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012553+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012554+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012592+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 92, in addrole
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012593+00:00 app[worker.1]: await user.add_roles(user, role)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012621+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 673, in add_roles
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012621+00:00 app[worker.1]: await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012651+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 243, in request
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012652+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise NotFound(r, data)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012699+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012735+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012735+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012736+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012772+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012832+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 935, in invoke
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012833+00:00 app[worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012863+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012863+00:00 app[worker.1]: await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012890+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012891+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-03-06T21:14:09.012932+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

Edit 2: removed user from add_role

```
2021-03-06T22:22:45.062172+00:00 app[worker.1]: Your bot is ready.
2021-03-06T22:22:52.026199+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command addrole:
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028082+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028089+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028089+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028092+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 94, in addrole
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028100+00:00 app[worker.1]: await user.add_roles(role)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028104+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 673, in add_roles
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028108+00:00 app[worker.1]: await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028111+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 241, in request
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028111+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise Forbidden(r, data)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028152+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028160+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028161+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028161+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028164+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028223+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 935, in invoke
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028224+00:00 app[worker.1]: await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028225+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028225+00:00 app[worker.1]: await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028225+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028226+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-03-06T22:22:52.028228+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: Role ID's are integers iirc, have you tried using the ID as number instead of as a string like you are doing right now?

Comment: Yep just tested that, still didn't work sadly

Comment: Regarding the second error: the bot cannot to add roles to the user, either it's too low in the hierarchy or it simply doesn't have the necessary permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    # Add the customer role to the user

    guild = ctx.guild # You can remove this if you don't need it for something other
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(810264985258164255)
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Hope this should now work :)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting as a str, So remove the "" you have.

Comment: Jesus christ, y'know when you've been staring at something for so long.... thank you

Comment: That still didn't work sadly, I really thought that was a golden solution

Comment: Is your bot role (the one you can't edit) higher than the person (maybe you) role

Comment: and replace discord.User with discord.Member

Comment: The Missing Perms error means your bot is missing perms, For example, to add a role. You (or a bot) needs "Manage Roles"

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add `user` to `user.add_roles()` again.

So if you try `user.add_roles(role)`, it should work.

Edit: You should now replace `discord.User` with `discord.Member`.

So it will look like this;

```py
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```